# word alignment - memory error in python

Tags: python, memory, alignment

```
******** Read from corpus ********************
NEWRESULT
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "em2.py", line 168, in <module>
main()
File "em2.py", line 165, in main
print  em_run(NEWSENTENCES)
File "em2.py", line 54, in em_run
for source, target in sentence_pairs] 
MemoryError
```

The above error is obtained when I tried to run the following program. Can any one help me to solve the error?

The following program takes two text files "sample1" and "sample2". "sample1" contain one sentence in Malayalam language with 14 words in the sentence. "sample2" contain the corresponding translation in English with 23 words in it. The program is to take corresponding word alignment between the two languages.

Actually the program works for sentence with maximum of 10 words. The problem arrives when the words are above 10.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from itertools import izip
from collections import defaultdict
import copy
import itertools
import operator
import codecs
import StringIO


def em_run(sentence_pairs):

#Run expectation-maximization on a list of pairs of the form
# `(source_tokens, target_tokens)`
# where `source_tokens` is a list of tokens in the source language and
#`target_tokens` is a list of tokens for a translationally equivalent
#sentence in the target language.
#Returns a mapping `(t1, t2) => p` where `t1` is a source-language
#token, `t2` is a target-language token, and the value `p` represents
#$P(t1|t2)$.


source_sentences, target_sentences = zip(*sentence_pairs)
#print " \n SOURCE SENTENCE"
#print "\n", source_sentences
#print "\n TARGET SENTENCE"
#print "\n", target_sentences

source_vocabulary = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(source_sentences))
#print "\nSOURCE VOCABULARY"
#print "\n", source_vocabulary

target_vocabulary = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(target_sentences))
#print "\n TARGET VOCABULARY"
#print "\n", target_vocabulary

# Value with which to initialize each conditional probability
uniform_prob = 1.0 / len(source_vocabulary)
#print len(source_vocabulary)
#print "\n INITIAL PROBABILITY VALUE\n"
#print uniform_prob

conditional_probs_old = None
conditional_probs = { (source_w, target_w) : uniform_prob 
                                                for source_w in source_vocabulary
                                                    for target_w in target_vocabulary}
#print "\n INITIAL CONDITIONAL PROBABILITY VALUE"
#print "\n", conditional_probs

#alignments = [(source,target) for source,target in sentence_pairs ]
alignments = [[zip(source, target_perm)
                        for target_perm in itertools.permutations(target)]
                            for source, target in sentence_pairs] 
#print "\n SET OF ALL POSSIBLE ALIGNMENTS\n"
#print alignments

'''fw=codecs.open('file_mal.txt','w','utf8')
fw.write(str(alignments))
fw.close()'''
# Repeat until convergence
i = 0
while conditional_probs_old != conditional_probs:
    conditional_probs_old = copy.copy(conditional_probs)
    alignment_probs = {
        i: {
            tuple(alignment):
            reduce(operator.mul, [conditional_probs[pair]
                for pair in alignment])
            for alignment in sentence_alignments
       }

for i, sentence_alignments in enumerate(alignments)
}



# Normalize alignment probabilities
for sentence_idx, sentence_alignments in alignment_probs.iteritems():
    total = float(sum(sentence_alignments.values()))
    probs = {alignment: value / total
        for alignment, value in sentence_alignments.iteritems()}
    alignment_probs[sentence_idx] = probs

# Now join all alignments and begin the maximization step: group
# by target-language word and collect corresponding
# source-language probabilities
word_translations = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))
for sentence_alignments in alignment_probs.itervalues():
    for word_pairs, prob in sentence_alignments.iteritems():
        for source_word, target_word in word_pairs:
    #print source_word
            word_translations[target_word][source_word] += prob

# Now calculate new conditional probability mapping, ungrouping
# the `word_translations` tree and normalizing values into
# conditional probabilities
st = []
words=[]
conditional_probs = {}

for target_word, translations in word_translations.iteritems():
    total = float(sum(translations.values()))
    for source_word, score in translations.iteritems():
        conditional_probs[source_word, target_word] = score / total
#print conditional_probs

for key,value in conditional_probs.iteritems():
    #print key[0]
    words.append(key[0])
    #for key,value in conditional_probs.iteritems():
#print words 
st=set(words)
#print st
for i in st:
    final(i,conditional_probs)


with codecs.open ('output_data.txt', 'w','utf8') as fp:
    for key,value in conditional_probs.iteritems():
        fp.write(key[0].decode('utf8')+" , "+key[1]+" : "+str(value))
    fp.write("\n")
return conditional_probs

def final(i,conditional_probs):
lst = []
output=StringIO.StringIO()
ha=[]
val=0
val1=0
#print i
fd=open('final.txt','a')
for key,value in conditional_probs.iteritems():
    if i in key[0]:
        val1=value
        if val<val1:
            lst=value
            key2=key[0]
            key3=key[1]
            val=value

        ha.append(value)
output.write(key2 + "," + key3 + '=' + str(val) + "   \n")
contents=output.getvalue()

fd.write(contents)
fd.close()
output.close() 
#print lst
#print ha

def main():

print "******** Read from corpus ********************"
NEWSENTENCES = []
with open("sample1") as textMal, open("sample2",) as textEn:
    for x, y in izip(textMal, textEn):
        x = x.strip().split()
        y = y.strip().split()
        NEWSENTENCES.append((x, y))
        #print x
    #print y

print "NEWRESULT"
print  em_run(NEWSENTENCES)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

sample1

ദൈവം വെള്ളങ്ങളുടെ മദ്ധ്യേ ഒരു വിതാനം ഉണ്ടാകട്ടെ; അതു വെള്ളത്തിന്നും വെള്ളത്തിന്നും തമ്മിൽ വേർപിരിവായിരിക്കട്ടെ എന്നു കല്പിച്ചു.

sample2

And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters.

Comment: Please put your code over here and also the sample1/2

Comment: Please also indent your code properly, also have you tried anything to debug the issue yourself? Does the issue also occur when *sample1* and *sample2* are smaller (like maybe a single line with 4-5 words) .

Comment: no error with sentences up to 10 words.